# Powershell script to copy files changed in last 4 hours from multiple location

Tags: windows, powershell

We have multiple path on server where logs are generating. Logs are configured to autorotate after certain logs. We want to copy those logs which are changed in last 4 hours to another drive for backup then zip it. To schedule we will configure a schedule in task scheduler to run every 4 hours.

We tried batch script but it is not able to search last modified file with time.

Could anyone help on this. We want to copy subfolders also from source to destination.

Below is the script I'm using, this extracting logs on day basic on hourly basic.
I want copy logs for last 4 hours without overwrite to the destination even if file with same name is found in source.

```
:: Below commands will check for existing files with name *ops*.zip, if found it will moved to L:\Archive folder

@ECHO OFF
::Destination folder, where log files compressed in zip will be copied
mkdir "L:\Archive"
SET DestinationDir=L:\Logs
::Archive folder, previous runs will be saved here
SET ArchiveDir=L:\Archive
SET FilePatternName=*ops*.zip

ECHO Zip files archiving......
FOR %%A IN ("%DestinationDir%\%FilePatternName%") DO (
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%%~A" "%ArchiveDir%\"
DEL /Q /F "%%~A"
)

SET Date=%date:~4%
set fdate=%Date:~0,2%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~6,4%
set time=%time::=%


ECHO Starting to copy the log files ......


ECHO Copying AdvancedFeatureServer logs ...
forfiles /P "E:\WORK\ops\AdvancedFeatureServer\LogFile" /s /D +%Date% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%Date% && (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y /F @path %DestinationDir%\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\AdvancedFeatureServer\LogFile\)"
forfiles /P "E:\WORK\ops\Advice\LogFile" /s /D +%Date% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%Date% && (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y /F @path %DestinationDir%\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\Advice\LogFile\)"
forfiles /P "E:\WORK\ops\Advice\Outbound" /s /D +%Date% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE 2> nul forfiles /M  @file /D -%Date% && (cmd /c xcopy /S /Y /F @path %DestinationDir%\ops_logs_%fdate%\%computername%\Advice\Outbound\Alert\)"



:: Below commands will Zip the folder


ECHO Zipping...

L:
cd L:\Logs


for /d %%X in (*ops*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "ops_logs_%fdate%_%time%.zip" "%%X\"
for /d %%X in (*ops*) do RMDIR "%%X" /S /Q


pause
```

Comment: Did you try doing it with `robocopy`?

Comment: Consider changing `Date=` and `set time=` to `dt=` and `tm=` since `%time%` and `%date%` are environmental variable. Just in case that's the issue with the result of your batch script, I wanted to advise on that at least.

Comment: I used this commands in Powershell but it is not creating folder:
      Get-ChildItem  -Path "D:\ops_logs\AdvancedFeatureServer"| where { 
      $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-4) } | % { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName 
    -Destination "C:\Temp\Logs\ops_logs_$(Get-Date -Format 
     "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")" }

Comment: Now it is not creating folder recursively which are present is source :
Get-ChildItem  -Path "D:\ops_logs\AdvancedFeatureServer"| where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-4) } | % { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Temp\Logs\ops_logs_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")\$env:computername\" -Force -Recurse }